# Disabling the dialogs shown when opening an application for the first time on OSX

Tags: macos, applications, python, gatekeeper

I am making an app on osx 10.9 using python 2.7. But when it is launched first time, warning comes.

> You are opening the application MYAPP for the first time. Are you sure
>   you want to open this application?
>
> The application is in a folder named Applications. To see the
>   application in the Finder without opening it, click Show Application.

So, how to avoid this warning. Does I need to make some changes in **info.plist of app**.

I had gone through this [Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/266176/disabling-the-dialogs-shown-when-opening-an-application-for-the-first-time) but nothing is mentioned about app side changes.

I don't want user to use any sort of command to run or do changes manually. User can disable by `"com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO"` for all or `"xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine Application.app"` for particular app.

I had also **signed** the app with developer ID.

So, how to disable this dialog box from popping.

Comment: `defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool false` doesn't even disable those dialogs. It only disables the dialogs about opening files downloaded from the internet.

Comment: Even if it is possible to disable from the user's side, I highly doubt there is a way to override from the application side. That would defeat the purpose of the warning, if it could be set to not show by malicious software.

Answer (score 1):

Simply right-click your application and choose "Open".  That immediately gets around Gatekeeper without disabling the feature (which is highly effective at keeping the mac safe from drive-by infections).